# How to try-restart every unit belonging to a target

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I have a set of service units that are WantedBy and PartOf a target. I want to restart the services that are already running and ignore the ones that were stopped at some point. Is this possible natively without the need of parsing some output?

Comment: The [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#try-restart%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6) states that `try-restart` will not affect units that are not running. Can you check if this works for you?

Comment: @Haxiel Using `try-restart` on a target will just restart everything PartOf that target, since the target itself is considered "active" by systemd.